# Visual Basic how to disable all checkbox?

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2010, checkbox

I'm working in Visual Basic 2010 Express

I want to disable all checkbox of a Form

Not only that, as you can see in the code, there are 49 checkbox. And everyone has an event, I want to save code and optimize it.

```
Public Class Form1
        Dim intNumber As Integer
        Dim arrNumber(0 To 5) As Integer
        Dim i, x, y As Integer
        Dim maxCheck = 6
        Dim count As Integer = 1

        Private Sub setCheckbox(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox9.Click, CheckBox8.Click, CheckBox7.Click, CheckBox6.Click, CheckBox5.Click, CheckBox49.Click, CheckBox48.Click, CheckBox47.Click, CheckBox46.Click, CheckBox45.Click, CheckBox44.Click, CheckBox43.Click, CheckBox42.Click, CheckBox41.Click, CheckBox40.Click, CheckBox4.Click, CheckBox39.Click, CheckBox38.Click, CheckBox37.Click, CheckBox36.Click, CheckBox35.Click, CheckBox34.Click, CheckBox33.Click, CheckBox32.Click, CheckBox31.Click, CheckBox30.Click, CheckBox3.Click, CheckBox29.Click, CheckBox28.Click, CheckBox27.Click, CheckBox26.Click, CheckBox25.Click, CheckBox24.Click, CheckBox23.Click, CheckBox22.Click, CheckBox21.Click, CheckBox20.Click, CheckBox2.Click, CheckBox19.Click, CheckBox18.Click, CheckBox17.Click, CheckBox16.Click, CheckBox15.Click, CheckBox14.Click, CheckBox13.Click, CheckBox12.Click, CheckBox11.Click, CheckBox10.Click, CheckBox1.Click
        If count < 6 Then
            count = count + 1
        Else


        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Wow. You need to quickly fix this code before it grows any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through all children of the form and if the child is of type `CheckBox`, disable it. This should take only a few lines of code: you can use the [`Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection of the form to access children. Something like:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In container.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
        ctrl.Enabled = False
    End If
Next
```

You should do the same with event handlers: instead of having that crazy `Handles` control list, just add the event handler to the checkboxes in a loop during runtime. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfty2w4e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) has an example on how to use `AddHandler` for that.